# angular: HttpClient delete failing when parsing response

Tags: angular

Currently I'm migrating from http to HttpClient (@angular/common/http). Everything is working except the delete statement. I assume angular tries to parse the result as I get an error:
"Unexpected end of JSON input ...". I'm not interested in the result detail, only if deletion was successfull or not.

So my code is:

Service:

```
public cancelReservation(reservationId: String) {

        if (!reservationId) {
            return null;
        }

        return this.httpClient.delete(environment.baseUrl + '/api/reservations/' + reservationId);
    }
```

Calling code:

```
this.reservationService.cancelReservation(this.reservation.id).subscribe (result => {
            this.handleSuccess();
        }, error => {
            this.handleError();
        });
```

I simplified the success and error handling. The post and get request is build the same way - but only delete is failing.

I tried an alternative, but with the same result:

```
this.reservationService.cancelReservation(this.reservation.id).toPromise().then(() => {
this.handleSuccess();
        }).catch(() => {
this.handleError();
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem.
Try to add `{ observe: 'response', responseType: 'text' }` to your request.
`this.http.post(this.createTagUrl, tagDetails, { observe: 'response', responseType: 'text' });`

Or change the version of HttpModule to 4.3.5. In this version it works.